# Inheritance and generic type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a generic model that implements a static method. Ideally I would like to avoid having to implement the method in the class that inherits the generic class. But I can't see how I can avoid setting the type.

It would be cool if I could get the type directly in the generic model...

Any suggestions?

```
abstract public class GenericFactory
    {
        public async Task<T> FindByUuid<T>(Guid uuid) where T:GenericModel, new()
        {
            return await rest.HttpGet<T>($"https://.../{uuid.ToString()}");
        }
    }

public class Contracts : GenericFactory
    {
        public async Task<Contract> FindByUuid(Guid uuid)
        {
            return await base.FindByUuid<Contract>(uuid);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: Sorry, my example was wrong. I removed and changed some things around to make my point clear. Instead I did the opposite. I've edited the code example to reflect this.**

Comment: I cannot find any static method in your code.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. I can´t see neither a `static` method nor know why you think you *have to* implement the `FindByUuid`-method.

Comment: I understand that the OP wants a static and inheritable method `FindByUuid`, but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: **Sorry**... In my attempt to pretty up and clearify things I removed too much. I'll post an edited example.

Comment: There **still** isn't a static method present in your code example. Please either remove static from your text, or add something static to your example. Also note that abstract != static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want your derived class `Contract` to only allow instances of `Contract` within your `FindByUuid`-method. Doing so won´t need to override the base-method, you just have to set the generic type-parameter to your class instead of the method itself:

```
public class GenericFactory<T> where T : GenericModel, new()
{
    public async Task<T> FindByUuid<T>(Guid uuid) 
    {
        return await rest.HttpGet<T>($"https://.../{uuid.ToString()}");
    }
}

public class Contracts : GenericFactory<Contract> { ... }
```

Now all instances of `Contracts` have the method `FindByUuid` that only accepts instances of `Contract`. No need for overriding - in your case it´s actually *hiding* as there allready exists a member with that name in the base-class.

Comment: I see your point. I was a bit too quick to post my code example though. I've edited it above.

I tried your method without luck though. VS complains that "constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations"

Comment: I updated my code, of course the generic constraint must be defined on the class, not at the method.

Comment: This works and is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you!